# Realistic energy output of a battery

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, batteries

An answer from the post ["Battery life with hot and cold wires"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/342077/173474) talks about Peukert's law related to the battery capacity. Now, within the scope of undergrad electromagnetism courses, the following are two common scenarios:
Case 1 : A circuit with only a battery and a resistor.
Case 2 : A circuit with a battery, a resistor and a capacitor.

However, it seems like in none of those cases Peukert's law is taken into account. Furthermore, books always say that voltage is *constant* and that if you know the resistance, then you can apply (the macroscopic version of) Ohm's law $V=IR$.
For case 1, the power $P=VI$ , so a beginner might believe that a battery keeps giving energy away forever.
For Case 2, one is supposed to use $I(t)=\frac{V_0}{R}e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}$ and assume that $V_0$ is constant.

**Questions:**

1. Peukert's law talks about current. But what about voltage? Does voltage in a battery also decrease in the presence of a resistor?
2. Is everybody supposed to ignore Peukert's law when doing undergrad electromagnetism ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an ideal battery, the terminal voltage is constant and independent of the load resistor, $R_L$. But real batteries have internal resistance, $R_b$, which must be considered in series with the load resistor. If $R_{b}<<<R_L$ then the battery terminal voltage will remain constant. If not, the battery terminal voltage will drop.

See the figure below. Note that there will be a voltage drop across $R_b$ when current flows, so that the terminal voltage will be the internal battery voltage minus the voltage drop. The voltage drop will be very small if $R_{b}<<<R_L$.

This also applies if the load resistor is in series with a capacitor.

Insofar as Peukert’s law is concerned, when I was an undergraduate it was not introduced. It is intended to give a better estimate of battery life than simply using the manufacturer’s ampere-hour rating.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If, in an ideal battery, the voltage is constant, why do you call it _terminal_ voltage? Also, if the voltage is constant, then according to $P=V^{2}/R$, the battery outputs energy infinitely nonstop?

Comment: I will update my answer to show the equivalent circuit.

Comment: Thank you for the diagram. Let's denote the terminal voltage (constant?) as $V_t$, then the power through the load resistor will be $P_L=V_t^2/R_L$. Does $R_L$ receive energy indefinitely ? If it does not, when does it stop?

Comment: The diagram only addresses the output voltage of the battery as a function of load current and internal battery resistance, not the amount of energy that is available from the battery. The energy delivered by the battery comes from the conversion of the battery"s chemical energy to electrical energy. The battery stops delivering energy when its chemical energy is spent. That's where the ampere-hour rating and Peukert's law come into play.

Comment: Got it. You said "If $R_b$ is not 'too small', the battery terminal voltage will drop". But the terminal voltage $V_t$ will _still_ be constant? In your first paragraph, you make it sound as if it were _not_ constant.
You also said "The battery stops delivering energy when its chemical energy is spent". This implies $V_t$ is a function of time (Or does it suddenly drop to zero when the energy is completely spent?). So, again, $V_t$ would not be constant, yet many exercises in undergrad textbooks treat is as a constant. So, which one is it? Is $V_t$ constant? It is not?

Comment: @evaristegd Where did I say "if Rb is not 'too small', the battery terminal will drop"? I said the voltage drop will be very small if Rb (its internal resistance) is much much less than RL (the load resistor). The undergrad text books I had did not get into the life of batteries. They either treat them as "ideal" which means zero internal resistance and the terminal voltage is independent of the load, or "real" but only with respect to the fact that there is internal resistance which effects terminal voltage, not with respect to how long they last.

Comment: I am sorry if I misinterpreted your first paragraph. And thank you so much for the kind explanations. I think your last sentence has cleared things up for me. I guess that, in most exercises, we will have to ignore how much batteries last.

Comment: @evaristegd No need to apologize and hope it helped

Comment: @evaristegd Then my answer is acceptable?

Comment: Question 1 was about how voltage is related to Peukert's law. But I'll rephrase: when the battery's chemical energy is spent, does that mean the voltage at that moment is zero (and therefore there is no current) ?

Comment: @evaristegd I'm not sure if I can go any further with this. Let's just say that as the chemical energy diminishes the ability of the battery to supply current to a load get less and less. In other words, it can only deliver current to a load resistor that that gets smaller and smaller until it reaches some point that no matter how low the load resistor is, the battery will not be able to deliver any current. At that point, it's all over. I can't add anything more.